# table creation fail in xcode for iPhone using sqlite

Tags: ios, ios4, sqlite

I used the following code for database creation in Xcode. It runs smoothly up to the `NSFilemanager` code, but after that it will terminating to `else` code that says `status.text=@"failed to open/create database";` so table can't be created.
I imported `sqlite3.h` and create `sqlDatabase` reference variable `sqlite3` still it doesn't work.

```
-(void)databaseCreate
{
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSString *dbPath;
    NSArray *dirPath;

    dirPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"dirpath::%@",dirPath);

    docsDir=[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"document directory::%@",docsDir);
    dbPath=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timerpro1.db"]];

    NSLog(@"database path::%@",dbPath);
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: dbPath] == NO)
    {
        const char *databsPath=[dbPath UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"treat filemanager");


        if(sqlite3_open(databsPath,&sqlDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *err;
            NSLog(@"create inside");
            const char *sql_stmt="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PRJDATA(ID INTEGER PRIMERY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,PRJ_NAME TEXT,PRJ_DATE TEXT,TIME_POINT1 TEXT,TIME_POINT2 TEXT,TIME_POINT3 TEXT,POINT2_DIFF_MIN TEXT,POINT2_DIFF_SEC TEXT,POINT3_DIFF_MIN TEXT,POINT3_DIFF_SEC TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(sqlDatabase, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK)
            {
                status.text=@"failed to create table";
            }
            sqlite3_close(sqlDatabase);
        }
        else
        {
            status.text=@"failed to open/create database";
        }
    }
    [fileManager release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you have to replace the reference to `NSDocumentationDirectory`  with `NSDocumentDirectory`.

Two asides:

1. When you get failures, you should examine `sqlite3_errmsg()`, as you'll often get descriptive errors. For example, your `sqlite3_exec()` statement will fail, even after you fix the `NSDocumentDirectory` mistake.

   If you look at the `sqlite3_errmsg()` error message, it will tell you that you have an error near the `AUTOINCREMENT` clause. If you look at the SQL carefully, you'll notice that you have misspelled `PRIMARY KEY`. That would be more difficult to find in the absence of the `sqlite3_errmsg()`, which brings our attention to the particular portion of the SQL.
2. You can simplify `dbPath` declaration:

   > ```
   > dbPath=[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"timerpro1.db"];`
   > ```

Comment: when i used sqlite3_errmsg(); in upper mentioned code then it will genrate log like **library routine called out of sequence** no any other error getting table also created.,.

Comment: @hirangsheth This is what the docs have to say about [library routine called out of sequence](http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=LibraryRoutineCalledOutOfSequence). In short, it means that the order in which you called the `sqlite3` functions was in the wrong order. The code of your above question (with my two fixes above), works fine for me, so I'm guessing you've changed your code a little? Perhaps trying another `sqlite3` function after you've closed your database? Maybe you can post that code in a new question if the solution is not leaping out at you.